# How to avoid scrolling in a signup screen in android if the input box has lot of fields(Needs to fit in a single screen for all models)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-palette

I need to avoid the scrolling of the screens in the android signup screen. How it will be possible if the screen is like below.

Now for me if the screen width is to small I need to scroll the page to see the changes.

How can I avoid this scroll for all models?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can divide these fields into separate pages. Like, on first screen you get name, email, password with continue button. On second screen, add date of birth and so on.